# Problem with MySQL Installer msi - can't see products that should be installed

Tags: mysql

I was using latest mysql installer web community 8.0.26. After choosing setup type and click execute in download section, nothing happens, and I cant see any 'products' listed in window. I checked temp files if anything is stored in and maybe ignoring it when trying to download, but still nothing. Choosing different setup type also wont change anything. Does anyone encountered similar problem?

[Heres screenshot from installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEnMI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the cancel button to go back to the home page. And try clicking the `Add` button in the right side[image]

Then click the `Edit` button and filter the things you want to install.
[image]

Comment: This option is not available for me, I guess this part of setup shows after initial installing, but I solved this problem around simply by downloading installer that contains all of packages (~400mb .msi instead of 4mb) and just installed them, works fine. Thanks for reminding though that installer itself works as reconfigurator and I can change settings through it.